# Movie selection app

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, angular.js

I'm new to Angular and I would like some advice on how I can improve my code. The main things that I want to focus on are decoupling and code correctness.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">

<fieldset>
    Select movie to display:
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.change('mortalkombat')">Mortal Kombat</button>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.change('princessbride')">Princess Bride</button>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.change('sherlockholmes')">Sherlock Holmes</button>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.change('tmnt')">TMNT</button>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.change('tmnt2')">TMNT2</button>
</fieldset>

<div ng-show="myCtrl.movie !== ''">

    <h1>{{myCtrl.info[0] + " (" + myCtrl.info[1] + ")"}}</h1>

    <div id=outerbox>
        <div id=overview>
            <div>
                <img ng-src="{{myCtrl.movie}}/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
            </div>

            <dl ng-repeat="over in myCtrl.overview">
                <dt>{{over.split(':')[0]}}</dt>
                <dd>{{over.split(':')[1]}}</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <div id=reviews>
            <div id=banner>
                <img ng-src="{{myCtrl.pic}}" alt="{{myCtrl.alt}}"/>
                {{myCtrl.info[2] + "%"}}
            </div>
            <div class=revcol>
                <span ng-repeat="rev in myCtrl.reviews | limitTo : (myCtrl.reviews.length / 2 |number:0)">
                    <p>
                        <img ng-src="{{myCtrl.image(rev['type'])}}" alt="{{rev['type']}}"/>
                        <q>{{rev['comment']}}</q>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <img src="/critic.gif" alt="Critic"/>
                        {{rev['name']}} <br/>
                        {{rev['from']}}
                    </p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class=revcol>
                <span ng-repeat="rev in myCtrl.reviews | limitTo : -(myCtrl.reviews.length / 2)">
                    <p>
                        <img ng-src="{{myCtrl.image(rev['type'])}}" alt="{{rev['type']}}"/>
                        <q>{{rev['comment']}}</q>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <img src="/critic.gif" alt="Critic"/>
                        {{rev['name']}} <br/>
                        {{rev['from']}}
                    </p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id=footer>
            <p>(1-{{myCtrl.reviews.length}}) of {{myCtrl.reviews.length}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myController', ['$http', function($http){
        this.movie = '';
        var myApp = this;
        myApp.info = [];
        myApp.overview = [];
        myApp.over = [];
        myApp.pic = '';
        myApp.alt = '';
        myApp.reviews = [];

        this.change = function(movie){
            this.movie = movie;
            $http.get("./" + movie + "/info.txt").success(function(data){
                myApp.info = data.split('\n');
                console.log(myApp.info);
                myApp.rank();
            });
            $http.get("./" + movie + "/overview.txt").success(function(data){
                myApp.overview = data.split('\n');
                console.log(myApp.overview);
            });
            $http.get("./" + movie + "/reviews.json").success(function(data){
                myApp.reviews = data;
                console.log(myApp.reviews);
            });
        };

        this.rank = function(){
            if(myApp.info[2] >= 60){
                myApp.pic = "/freshbig.png";
                myApp.alt = "Fresh";
            }
            else{
                myApp.pic = "/rottenbig.png";
                myApp.alt = "Rotten";
            }
        };

        this.image = function(r){
            if(r === 'FRESH'){
                return "/fresh.gif";
            }
            else{
                return "/rotten.gif";
            }
        };

    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to decouple the view (html part) from the controller. You can do this by using `$scope`.

For example, instead of writing

```
<span ng-repeat="rev in myCtrl.reviews | limitTo : (myCtrl.reviews.length / 2 |number:0)">
```

You should

```
<span ng-repeat="rev in reviews | limitTo : (reviews.length / 2 |number:0)">
```

In the controller you put reviews in the `$scope`.
Please see this doc https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02